# Mirror on premise MariaDB to Azure SQL?

Tags: database, azure, mariadb

I need to mirror an on premise MariaDB to an Azure SQL Server. The mirroring needs to happen daily. I read through the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-data-in-replication but it is not clear to me if this is a fully automated approach.

I also found https://mariadb.com/kb/en/moving-data-between-sql-server-and-mariadb/ describing a manual approach.

Is there an out-of-the-box solution in Azure for this problem?
How can I achieve such a mirroring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the data from MariaDB to azure SQL, you can use azure data factory copy activity.
Go to manage tab click on Linked service
you will get below tab

[image]

In that search for MariaDB and select the MariaDB connecter.
Image for reference:

[image]

Configure the service details, test the connection, and create the new linked service.

[image]

Create a pipeline and create copy activity create dataset using MariaDB linked service.  To copy data from MariaDB, set the source type in the copy activity to **MariaDBSource**.
Sink should be azure SQL as per your requirements.

Reference: Microsoft Document [Copy data from MariaDB - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mariadb?tabs=data-factory)

To run this activity daily you can add Schedule trigger.
Image for reference:

[image]